# .NET MAUI image from source in collection view is not working on IOS, while fine working on Android emulator and Windows

Tags: android, ios, .net, maui, cross-platform

.NET MAUI image from source in collection view is not working on IOS, while fine working on Android emulator and Windows.

I am trying to load byte[] array from SQLite database, then convert it to memory stream and after equalize to ImageSource in order to add Image to ObservableCollection and display in CollectionView. It works well on Android Emulator and on Windows. There are not appearing any errors.

### Here are images of the problem.
How it looks on Windows

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ymXVjoTIzRkhP9rHe50_9rLj3h6jHbZ_/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I5sPPMtemUK4vEp8kODZZNljy5pdKA-w/view?usp=sharing

### How it looks on IOS

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VUIrKHJ7cR_AKxRYDRcgKON9SA-L60z5/view?usp=sharing

### Here are my snippets of code:

ViewModel

```
using PlumbingCompany.Services;
using PlumbingCompany.Models;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Data;

    public partial class Page2ViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
    
        private readonly IJobService _jobService;
    
        public Page2ViewModel(IJobService jobService)
        {
            _jobService = jobService;     
    
            ID = GlobalVariables.CurrentID;
            GetPhotoList(ID);
         }
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Page2Data _Page2Data = new Page2Data();
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private ImageSource imageSource;
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _Name;
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string _ImageData;
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        private byte[] _Bytes;
    
        [ObservableProperty]
        int _ID;
    
        public ObservableCollection<Page2Data> ImagesCollection { get; private set; } = new 
        
        ObservableCollection<Page2Data>();
        
        public List<Page2Data> ImagesList { get; set; } = new List<Page2Data>();
         
         [RelayCommand]
         public async void GetPhotoList(int ID)
         {
             ImagesCollection.Clear();
             var imageList = await _jobService.GetImagesList(ID);
             if (imageList?.Count > 0)
             {
                 imageList = imageList.ToList();
                 foreach (var image in imageList)
                 {
                     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image.Bytes);
                     Page2Data = image;
                     Page2Data.imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => ms);
                     ImagesCollection.Add(Page2Data);
                 }
                 ImagesList.Clear();
                 ImagesList.AddRange(imageList);
                 ImagesSaved = ImagesList.Count();
             }
             else ImagesSaved = 0;
        
         }
    }
```

Model

```
using SQLite;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Models
{
    [SQLite.Table("Page2Data")]
    public class Page2Data
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Image_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
        public string RowID { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Bytes64 { get; set; }
        [Ignore]
        public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```

View

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PlumbingCompany.Views.Page2_PhotoUpload"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:PlumbingCompany.Data"
             xmlns:Models="clr-namespace:PlumbingCompany.Models"
             x:DataType="viewModels:Page2ViewModel"
             Title="2. Photo upload">

...

<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" MinimumHeightRequest="500">
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <CollectionView x:Name="ImageListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ImagesCollection}" >
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame Margin="10" Padding="10" MinimumHeightRequest="300" MaximumHeightRequest="500">
                            <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="50">
                                <Image  
                                    Source= "{Binding ImageSource }" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    MaximumHeightRequest="1024"
                                    MinimumHeightRequest="300"
                                    MaximumWidthRequest="768"
                                    MinimumWidthRequest="300"/>
                                <VerticalStackLayout>
                                    <Label 
                                        Text="{Binding Name}" 
                                        LineBreakMode="CharacterWrap"
                                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                                        VerticalOptions="End"
                                        Padding="15"
                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                    <Button 
                                        Text="Delete" 
                                        TextColor="White" 
                                        Background="#9B082B"
                                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Start"  
                                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.DeleteImageButtonTypedCommand, Source={x:Reference ImageListView}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        />
                                </VerticalStackLayout>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView >

...

</ContentPage>
```

View C# Background File

```
using PlumbingCompany.Data;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Views;

public partial class Page2_PhotoUpload : ContentPage
{

    public Page2_PhotoUpload(Page2ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

### Service File

```
using SQLite;
using PlumbingCompany.Models;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Services
{
    public class JobService : IJobService
    {
    private SQLiteAsyncConnection _dbConnection;

    private async Task SetUpDb()
    {
         ...
    }

    public async Task<int> AddImage(Page2Data page2Data)
    {
        return await _dbConnection.InsertAsync(page2Data);
    }

    public async Task<List<Page2Data>> GetImagesList(int ID)
    {
        var page2Data = await _dbConnection.Table<Page2Data>().Where(i => i.Id == ID).ToListAsync();
    return page2Data;
    }
```

## IService

```
using PlumbingCompany.Models;

namespace PlumbingCompany.Services
{
   public interface IJobService
   {
       Task SetUpDataBase();
   
       Task<int> AddImage(Page2Data page2Data);

       Task<int> DeleteImage(Page2Data page2Data);

       Task<List<Page2Data>> GetImagesList(int ID);
    }
}
```

### How it looks in SQLite database viewer

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wUQa998JeYMGYnqgfiFA3LZSEdC5bkrh/view?usp=sharing

Also I tried to use NUGET CommunityToolkit package's converter called "ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter" and result was the same: everything worked fine on android emulator and Windows, but not on IOS device.(It also displayed empty places instead of photos on IOS)

Comment: What if you click the back button and open the Page2_PhotoUpload again, can the images be displayed correctly?

Comment: Alexandar May - MSFT, no,  nothing changes, if i go back and then open the Page2_PhotoUpload again. I also tried to change the orientation of the device, like to rerender the view, but nothing changes ether.

Comment: Thanks for your update, May I know how do you save the image into the db? Would you mind providing the database code related to that part?

Comment: Thank you, for coming back to my question,  
Alexandar May. 
I have added additional information about way I add images to database using Service, iService and also added an image of database viewer, to understand how it looks in database.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I noticed that you tested it on a real iOS device, have you tried on a simulator? Also, you can raise a issue report: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues on Github.

Comment: I didn't try to run in on simulator. I only tried to run it on Android emulator, and it worked well, like on widows. I have some suspicions, that IOS SQLite database stores bytes array in another way, than on  Android or Windows, so that is why IOS may not display images converted from bytes into stream. But that's just my suspicion. 

Yeap, I thing I will try to post my question on "github.com/dotnet/maui/issues"

Comment: Thanks for your response, I mean the iOS simulator but there could be some issue when converting from bytes into stream on iOS as you said.